# Is it possible to `mock.patch` functions run in multiprocessing (using `spawn`)?

Tags: python, macos, mocking, python-multiprocessing, python-3.8

Is it possible to `mock.patch` a function that will be run in a subprocess, which is created using the `multiprocessing` module with the `start method` set to `spawn`?

If there is no solution to patching a child process which is not `forked`, what would be the right solution to bypass this problem?

It's important to say that switching to use fork is not a solution to my problem.
As of python3.8-macOS, the default behavior for the multiprocessing start method is `spawn`.

From the `multiprocessing` documentation:

`Changed in version 3.8: On macOS, the spawn start method is now the default. The fork start method should be considered unsafe as it can lead to crashes of the subprocess. See bpo-33725.`.

Example code (Run on macos with python >= 3.8):

```py
import multiprocessing
import unittest
from unittest import mock


def baz(i):
    print(i)


def bar(i):  #  Middle function to avoid a pickeling problem with mocks
    baz(i)


def foo():
    with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as pool:
        pool.map(bar, [i for i in range(10)])


class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch(f'{__name__}.baz', return_value=None)
    def test_case(self, mock):
        # multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork', force=True)
        foo()
```

The `baz` function is not patched in the spawned processes (and hence, it prints) as can be seen in the following output.
Changing the default start method (commented in code) solves the problem

Output:

```
============================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.0, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.2, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/alonmenczer/dev/path_test/proj
collected 1 item

mp_spawn.py 0
1
4
5
6
7
8
9
2
3
.

=============================================================================== 1 passed in 0.27s ================================================================================
```

Comment: It might help if you add a code snippet demonstrating the problem. Like this is my `foo()`, that is being ran concurrently by `main()`. And here is `test_foo()` that tries to assert something.

Comment: Added an example

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with a slightly different use case on macOS running python 3.9.16. Setting the start method to "fork" indeed solves this, but I am not sure what are the implications of doing that. I can also confirm that this seems to be macOS specific, and does not come up on Ubuntu.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/65499545/691415 provides a solution

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would rather prefer to use `mock`. But if the library doesn't work, mocking can be achieved directly. E.g.:

```
def my_mock_baz(func):
    def _mock_baz(i):
        print(42)

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        global baz
        backup = baz
        baz = _mock_baz
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        baz = backup
        return res

    return inner
```

And then in the test:

```
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @my_mock_baz
    def test_case(self):
        foo()
```

Of course, I other cases, mocking would be more difficult, but with the flexibility of Python it should be not too hard.

Side note: your problem doesn't reproduce in my Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8.2.

Comment: Indeed, `spawn` was changed to be the default only for macos.
You can change the start method using
`multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)`

Answer (score -6):

[yes it definitely is it just depends how](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation for the answer?
How does this solve the issue?
What did you mean by adding a link to the multiprocessing module doc?

Comment: The question was about unit testing, with mocking functions run with multiprocessing.